# Using EXE's instead of DLL's as plugins - Ways to "one way, one time" transfer information

Tags: delphi, winapi

***tldr; at bottom.***

Ok, so once again an interesting problem and I'm looking for a fun and interesting solution.

My current project involves being very modular, meaning the program functionality will be easily changed based on different modules and the program would adapt.

So I started out with the typical route, which is using DLL plugins. Now this is just way to normal, I want to think outside the box a bit.

The modules included in my program are long running campaigns that may take weeks to finish, and there will be many running at a time. So stability is a big issue, so I thought about what Google Chrome does. Processes, not DLLs or threads.

So I have a framework going and I need a way to get some information about each module (which are now EXEs). Now for my DLL framework I was exporting a "Register" function that would fill in some information.

So I thought to myself, hey EXEs can export functions, let's see if that actually works...It doesn't. I did some research into how Windows handles theses things and I don't feel like hacking the PE headers on the fly (but it's the out of the box kind of thinking I'm going for).

I'm planning on using named pipes and CLI parameters to transfer data between the main program and the module exe's. I could use that in a register fashion, but I want to here other peoples thoughts.

***tldr: I'm using EXE's instead of DLL's for plugins. Looking for a way to easily export one time information like a exported "Register" function would on a DLL. Thoughts?***

Comment: Chrome's approach is more about instability of components.

Comment: How is that different from stability in general?

Comment: @thieving in chrome the browser does not have control over the code it runs but you do

Comment: True, but I'm not perfect either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might still consider having the modules written as DLLs with defined entrypoints (e.g., the Register function).  Then you write the executable that loads the specified DLL.  Your main application would fire off the driver executable and give it a name of a plugin DLL.

That way it is still easy to define and export the set of APIs that must be provided yet still run it as a separate process.  The one executable that you write can load the specified DLL and then handle the necessary IPC with the main app.

Comment: I did think of that, but it seems like too much code for just keeping the exporting functionality of the DLL. Main --> DLL --> EXE? 

Unless I'm missing a crucial benefit of segregating it like this.

Comment: @ThievingSix: Mark was referring to a `Main -> EXE -> DLL` model instead.  The Main app spawns a loader EXE, telling it which DLL to load.  The loader EXE then loads the DLL and calls the exported `Register()` function like before.  The EXE then communicates back and forth with the Main app as needed.  That way, the DLL is running in its own process, without having to re-write the DLLs you already have.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I would only have one generic EXE that will load the different plugins. I like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a protocol via the stdin/stdout, named pipes, sockets, etc.

Comment: I actually completely forgot about stdin/stdout!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used 'plain' COM for several projects, and objects inheriting from TAutoObject. The bonusses here are IDL; the interopability with .Net, VBA and other non-Delphi things; and the fact that implementors still can choose wether to supply a DLL, an exe, an NT-service, and optionally run hosted over the network (COM+/DCOM). There may be several considerations you should handle about multi-threading and locking, but I found all that I needed to know online.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, not use symbols exported by a (running) exe since it is running in another boundary. But, you can load an exe as an image (as you would do with a library) using LoadLibrary(Ex) and then, use the functions exported by the exe. I have tested (just for fun) when debugging PeStudio. See the snapshot below of chrome.exe loaded in the process space of PeStudio.exe using LoadLibrary.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I did try that. It seems LoadLibrary() on EXE's is limited to loading resources from the exe, not exported functions.

Comment: ntoskrnl.exe imports AND exports many functions. As a matter of fact, many of these exported functions are the ones you indirectly use when using WIN32. Of course, you can LoadLibrary on an EXE and use the functions exported by the EXE!

Comment: Hmm, I will have to try it again then ;)